# Реализовать функцию addDigits()

Tags: javascript, функции

Нужно создать функцию, которая будет принимать неотрицательное целое число и складывать все входящие в него цифры до тех пор, пока не останется одна цифра.
Например, есть число 49:

4 + 9 = 13

1 + 3 = 4

Решение целиком писать не нужно, просто хочу понять, какой алгоритм у данной функции и с помощью чего можно её реализовать.

Comment: *какой алгоритм у данной функции* Поделить на 9, вернуть остаток. Если остаток ноль, а число не ноль - вернуть 9. Школьная программа, класс седьмой, наверное...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Число дает такой же остаток от деления на 9, как и его сумма цифр. При этом если число делится на 9 нацело, то остаток будет равен 0. А поскольку сумма цифр равна нулю только у единственного числа (0), то скорректировать это просто:

```js
function addDigits(x) {
  let m = x % 9;
  return x == 0 ? 0 : m == 0 ? 9 : m;
}

console.log(addDigits(0));
console.log(addDigits(9));
console.log(addDigits(67));
console.log(addDigits(333));
console.log(addDigits(111111111));
console.log(addDigits(444));
console.log(addDigits(1111111111));
console.log(addDigits(123456789078));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

То же самое в виде гольфа:

```js
f=x=>x?x%9||9:0

console.log(f(0));
console.log(f(9));
console.log(f(67));
console.log(f(333));
console.log(f(111111111));
console.log(f(444));
console.log(f(1111111111));
console.log(f(123456789078));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот короткий и красивый вариант, кмк. Юзаем методы массивов и чуть рекурсии.

```js
function add(str) {
  if(typeof str !== 'string') {
    str = str.toString();
  }
  let res = str.split('').reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return acc += parseInt(cur);
  }, 0);
  if(res.toString().split('').length > 1) {
   res = add(res.toString());
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(add(999));
console.log(add(888));
console.log(add(88));
console.log(add(1));
```

Comment: В результате должна быть одна цифра.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko `4 + 9 = 13`. Это в условии задачи. Приходит число, разбивается за цифры и цифры складываются. Где про одну цифру в результате написано??

Comment: Ну, вот здесь написано `49:

4 + 9 = 13

1 + 3 = 4`. Видите, надо складывать до тех пор, пока в результате не останется одна цифра. В данном примере 2 итерации.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вижу. Теперь работает и при таком условии.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sum(x) {
  while (x > 9) {
    for (var y=x, x=0; y; y=Math.floor(y/10)) {
      x += y % 10
    }
  }
  
  return x
}

console.log(sum(0))
console.log(sum(9))
console.log(sum(67))
console.log(sum(333))
console.log(sum(111111111))
console.log(sum(444))
console.log(sum(1111111111))
console.log(sum(123456789078))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```